# RabbitMQ message expiry Notification

Tags: java, java-8, rabbitmq

Is there a way we can push messages to RabbitMQ and have an expiry time for it and once it expires, it should provide a notification.
Or
Is there a way we can deliver the messages in RabbitMQ after a certain amount of time. For example, I want to push a message in the queue and wants it to get delivered after 10 seconds..and simultaneously next messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question, the routing of messages that have expired due to a per-message TTL is a feature of the [RabbitMQ dead letter exchange (DLX)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Regarding a delay, this is not something supported by RabbitMQ out of the box, nor in my opinion should it be a feature of a message broker. I can't imagine a legitimate use case where you would deliberately want to introduce a delay into a message queue. In fact, it is a design goal of any message broker to *minimize* delay with enqueued messages. If you find a delay to be appropriate, then it is also likely that a message queue is not the appropriate means of conveyance.

Answer (score 1):

The RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin adds a new exchange type to RabbitMQ where messages routed by that exchange can be delayed if the users chooses to do so.

You can use it in a way like described below.

```
// ... elided code ...
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");
channel.exchangeDeclare("my-exchange", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
// ... more code ...
```